# What's the difference between Convert.ToInt32 and Int32.Parse?

Tags: c#

In `C#` there you can convert a string to Int32 using both `Int32.Parse` and `Convert.ToInt32`. What's the difference between them? Which performs better? What are the scenarios where I should use `Convert.ToInt32` over `Int32.Parse` and vice-versa?

Comment: @vanneto: the question might be a duplicate, but the answers aren't.

Answer (score 17):

If you look with [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/) or [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/) into the `mscorlib` you will see the following code for `Convert.ToInt32`

```
public static int ToInt32(string value)
{
    if (value == null)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return int.Parse(value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
}
```

So, internally it uses the [int.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.parse.aspx) but with the `CurrentCulture`.
And actually from the code is understandable why when I specify `null` like a parameter this method does not throw an exception.

Answer (score 7):

Basically `Convert.ToInt32` uses 'Int32.Parse' behind scenes but at the bottom line 
`Convert.ToInt32` A `null` will return 0. while in `Int32.Parse` an Exception will be raised.

Answer (score 3):

> Int32.Parse (string s) method converts the string representation of a number to its 32-bit signed integer equivalent. When s is a null reference, it will throw ArgumentNullException.

whereas

> Convert.ToInt32(string s) method converts the specified string representation of 32-bit signed integer equivalent. This calls in turn Int32.Parse () method. When s is a null reference, it will return 0 rather than throw ArgumentNullException.

Answer (score 2):

> Convert.ToInt32 (string value)

From MSDN:

Returns a 32-bit signed integer equivalent to the value of value. -or- Zero if value is a null reference (Nothing in Visual Basic).
The return value is the result of invoking the `Int32.Parse` method on value.